# Utilities for finding x/y screen coordinates

Tags: software-rec, display

I have an application that needs the user to enter the x and y location of a couple of items on the screen. [Yes, this is crap and I'll replace it, but for now...]

On Mac OS X, I'm using Snapz Pro X.  When I choose to take a snap of a selection, the interface displays the mouse cursor location.  This is OK for my personal use, but I can't ask users to buy a $69 program for this function.

I thought I had a solution with the built-in program "Grab", but it reports the coordinates from the bottom left, and I need it from the top left.

I don't have access to Windows; not sure what to use there.  I've not even been able to come up with good search terms since mouse and coordinates and x/y are so common.  Ideas are welcome there.  Extra credit:  same x/y finder for Linux.  A Java program would be OK too, since the main application is in Java.

Comment: ACK!  I've asked 4 questions in 1 (platform.each).  But it would have seemed dumb to ask a separate question for each platform.  Hm.

Comment: The answers you folks posted helped me refine my search terms -- so I was able to find some more answers.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Uhm.  Snapz Pro X has a 15-day free trial.  After that, it watermarks the screen captures.  And you don't even want the actual screen capture.  Unless you think that's abusing the free trial.  It's a great program; maybe they'll get hooked and buy it.

Comment: I might as well be my own sock puppet at this point.

Comment: See also [Program for getting the cursor's x,y coordinates?](http://superuser.com/questions/244267/program-for-getting-the-cursors-x-y-coordinates) with another suggestion for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Quix App](http://quixapp.com/) is a browser bookmarklet: cross-platform, no plug-ins.

Drag the bookmarklet to your bookmarks toolbar.  Click.  Enter the command **ruler**, and you get a nice cross-hairs cursor to work with, and an informative pop-up with all the coordinates.

[image]

Comment: Quix is still mentioned at the Yoast site, but the app seems to have gone away. https://yoast.com/online-marketing-tools/

Answer (score 7):

**Warning : This is an old post.
This product is no longer available.**

For Windows you can use [Point Position](https://www.snapfiles.com/get/pointpos.html) :

The way to use the application is very simple:

- Move the window by putting your mouse
  cursor in the cross which is in the
  middle of it, and point one of the
  four corner arrows into the place of
  the screen you want to define.
- Then push the button corresponding to the pointing arrow.
- The text entries will take the color of the button, and they will show you the exact pointing position.

[image]

Comment: feel free to upvote my recommendation :)

Comment: I'll just upvote both of you, though merging answers like this would be better!

Comment: Dead link. :(  .

Comment: @Almo: This answer is from 2009 and this product has disappeared since many years. I added a warning.

Comment: Thanks! @harrymc :)

Answer (score 5):

**[Point Position](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/pointpos.html)** (for Windows) is a simple tool that lets you pick the coordinates for any point on your screen (using X,Y axis). Simply point one of the four corner arrows at the spot on your screen that you want to define and click the button to display the X/Y coordinates.

*Point Position is freeware.*

Comment: Upvote done. Isn't my recommendation beautiful, image and all? Would be a great pity to delete it :)

Comment: I'll just upvote both of you, though merging answers like this would be better!

Comment: @Ivo: No problem. We also upvoted each other.

Comment: @Molly: It seems like the image carried the day. My apologies.

Comment: Image was helpful, but since the answers were essentially the same, I accepted the one with lower reputation.  Not sure why that would matter with reps in the Ks though.

Comment: "Sorry! This program is no longer available for download from our site. It may have been discontinued or become obsolete."

Answer (score 4):

For windows, you can use a powershell script with [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.cursor.position)

e.g.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
while (1) {
    $X = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position.X
    $Y = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position.Y

    Write-Host -NoNewline "`rX: $X | Y: $Y"
}
```

(copied and modified from https://norbertvajda.wordpress.com/2018/12/29/get-the-cursor-position-with-powershell/)

Comment: Opted not to improve this base version in case someone writes a better version of the overwrite function: mine works but suffers from a bit of stutter https://superuser.com/a/1731782/139701

Answer (score 3):

For Macintosh, use the built-in screen capture function.  Press Command-Shift-4 to take a picture of part of the screen.  The cursor switches to a crosshairs cursor that includes the x/y screen coordinates.  Press ESC to cancel the operation

Comment: That works, but it's kind of tough to use in practice.  The screen continues to update under the cursor (popups and junk in this case), plus the x/y numbers have poor contrasting colors and they're tiny.  It sounds better to use the Grab program -- and teach them how to subtract the Y value from their screen height.  You already have an ugly UI, what's one subtraction?

Answer (score 3):

I was led to this page through a query of my own. I had a further search around and found xev (on Linux and Mac OS X.)

Here's the Mac OS X documentation: http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xev.1.html

The Bash commands

```
$ root=`xwininfo -root | grep xwininfo | sed 's/.*0x/0x/; s/ .*//'`

$ xev -id $root
```

provided me with the information required. :)

Comment: It is important to know that on OS X, the `xev` command requires installation of X11. This is an optional installation on later OS X systems.

Answer (score 3):

```
$lastX = ""
$lastY = ""
Clear-Host
while (1) {
    $X = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position.X
    $Y = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position.Y
    if(($lastX -ne $X -or $lastY -ne $Y)) {
        Write-Host -NoNewline "                           " 
        $lastX = $X
        $lastY = $Y
    }
    Write-Host -NoNewline "`rX: $X | Y: $Y"
}
```

Based on the answer by JamesG3D, fixed it so it doesn't leave extraneous characters on-screen.

Answer (score 2):

I used [Cursor Position](http://download.cnet.com/Cursor-Position/3000-2383_4-75449858.html) from CNET.com:

> From [Mattlav Software](http://download.cnet.com/windows/mattlav-software/3260-20_4-10054855-1.html): Cursor Position allows you to work out the exact X and Y position of your cursor even as you move it, it also tells you how many pixels you have gone across if you move the cursor with the application open.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some details as to how the application solves the question? thanks.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: That looks much better now.

Comment: Nice app! Runs on Windows (not a dig, just noting since I included all platforms in the question).

Comment: Looks like this link is broken now

Answer (score 1):

For Mac OS X, [xScope](http://xscopeapp.com/) is pretty good. Turn on the **Loupe** (magnify) tool to make it easier to see exactly where you are. Then use the **Crosshair** tool to locate the exact spot you need.

If you'd like to measure your spot from a place that is not relative to the screen origin, move the cursor to your local 0,0, then press `Command-0` to set that spot as 0,0.

xScope is a commercial product from [The iconfactory](http://iconfactory.com/home). The app shows up in bundles regularly. But it must be worthwhile. Heck, the latest version boasts

> 70+ new features

Comment: Sockpuppet!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

As of this writing (2022), the links were dead for both Point Position and Cursor Position, but I found a similar program called [MPos](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mpos/) on SourceForge. Just run the executable and you get a draggable display showing the current mouse coordinates.

Comment: Fair warning the code in question uses some questionable practices like code weaving (why?), for what should be a fairly simplistic, no-nonsense utility... It appears to be some bootstrap code for doing things like updates, but the code for these dependencies is not provided. I would approach with caution.

Answer (score 1):

13 years later...

I found this thread searching for a quick solution to the same issue and wanted to share my own solution with you for desktop PC.

I took a screenshot (Fn + Prt Sc) and pasted that into Photoshop. I then used the Rectangular Marquee Tool to select the area that I needed the coordinates of and Photoshop gave me them on the right hand side of the screen.

[Screen Coordinates Via Photoshop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDCq9.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

you can use this from the pyautogui docs:

```
#! python3
import pyautogui, sys
print('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')
try:
    while True:
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        positionStr = 'X: ' + str(x).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).rjust(4)
        print(positionStr, end='')
        print('\b' * len(positionStr), end='', flush=True)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\n')
```

python 2:

```
#! python
import pyautogui, sys
print('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')
try:
    while True:
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        positionStr = 'X: ' + str(x).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).rjust(4)
        print positionStr,
        print '\b' * (len(positionStr) + 2),
        sys.stdout.flush()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

For Java, you can use the PointerInfo class, introduced in Java 1.5.

```
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;

public class Portia {
     public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(10000);  // some time for user to position mouse
        Point spot = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
        System.out.println(
                String.valueOf(spot.getX())
                +","+
                String.valueOf(spot.getY()));
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Skitch* from [Evernote](http://evernote.com/skitch/) includes an x/y coordinate display while taking a screen snap. The numbers are small and don't have any contrast layer -- so they're hard to see on a black background. Skitch is currently free.

[image]

Comment: Skitch is still mentioned in the Evernote help pages, but the link to the product takes you to the Evernote home page. Everything changes. https://help.evernote.com/hc/en-us/sections/200579197-Skitch

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [Chrome browser](https://www.google.com/chrome/), there is a well-maintained extension called [coordinates](https://github.com/Evaw/coordinates). It shows coordinates for the page, the screen, and can measure an area by dragging.

Answer (score 0):

The screen capture function from [WeChat](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/wechat/XPFCKBRNFZQ62G?hl=en) is also able to show the coordinates (X, Y)) and color (RGB) where your mouse cursor is.

This is what the output looks like:

[image: Output]