# Program for getting the cursor's x,y coordinates?

Tags: windows-xp, display, screen-capture, coordinates

Is there a program which lets you easily get the x,y coordinates for your cursor?

Basically, I move my cursor to somewhere on my screen, it shows me the x,y coordinates and has an option to copy them to the clipboard or export them somehow.

I can already do this if I take a screenshot and open it in MS Paint, then as I move the mouse cursor over the screenshot it shows the coordinates in the status bar, however I have to manually write them down, hence its not convenient.

Comment: You might clarify this by specifying OS, and do you mean terminal coordinates, or GUI coordinates, and whether relative to window or screen. But, most GUI test recording tools can do that.

Comment: @Keith I'm on windows XP, and I'm not sure what the difference is

Comment: You may also want to look at [this](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread6727.html).

Comment: See also [Utilities for finding x/y screen coordinates](http://superuser.com/questions/85822/utilities-for-finding-x-y-screen-coordinates) with 6 answers, some for Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pegtop's [**PMeter**](http://www.pegtop.de/pmeter/) can do this.

It also has a ruler and a color picker:

[image: (here be screenshots)]

---

Programmatically, this is done using [`GetCursorPos()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648390%28VS.85%29.aspx) Win32 API, or [`Control.MousePosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseposition.aspx) in .NET.

In other words, it's do-it-yourself time. Copy this to `MousePos.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Coords {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        bool copy = (args.Length == 1 && String.Compare(args[0], "/c") == 0);
        Point point = Control.MousePosition;
        string pos = String.Format("{0}x{1}", point.X, point.Y);
        if (copy) {
            Clipboard.SetText(pos);
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine(pos);
        }           
    }
}
```

If you have .NET Framework, compile with:

```
csc MousePos.cs /r:System.dll /r:System.Windows.Forms.dll /r:System.Drawing.dll
```

Copy to clipboard:

```
mousepos /c
```

The C# compiler, `csc.exe`, can be found in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5` (the version may vary; you can use whichever you have).

Comment: It only seems to show the coordinates, but doesn't have any way to copy them? I'd like something that can copy the coordinates

Comment: Wow that picture is really confusing... for lesser mortals. Someone else told me it was (they are a "Lesser Mortal"), so I assume it should be (for them).

Comment: @Click: See update.