# Is there an OS X tool for finding coordinates, pixel color and measuring distances on the screen?

Tags: macos, software-rec

Is there a software for OS-X that will do all those tasks? Finding screen-coordinates (x,y), the pixel color below pointer, and distance between 2 points?

Comment: See also [Utilities for finding x/y screen coordinates](http://superuser.com/questions/85822/utilities-for-finding-x-y-screen-coordinates).

Comment: related: [Retrieve image coordinates at mouse cursor in Preview.app](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/65162/55266)

Answer (score 23):

You can show screen coordinates if you start taking a screenshot by pressing ⇧⌘4:

[image]

You can also use it to measure the width and height of areas:

[image]

To abuse bundled applications even further, it's easy to get the diagonal in AppleScript Editor:

```
(114 ^ 2 + 89 ^ 2) ^ 0.5
```

You can see the color of pixels with DigitalColor Meter:

[image]

Comment: You don't have to fire up AppleScript Editor to perform a calculation like that. Spotlight will do it for you too.

Comment: How can I do this on Windows? To show those coordinates below?

Answer (score 1):

Coordinates | Digital Color Meter -> View -> Show Mouse Location

Comment: Is this part of the operating system?

Comment: Where does someone find "Coordinates" to start this path?  Does "Show Mouse Location" give you screen coordinates, pixel color, and distance between 2 points?

Comment: App named "digital color meter".  For what it's worth, this does not give you screen coordinates as a whole, but per screen (if you're using a multi-monitor setup)

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to add to Lri well put answer that if you need a light-weight alternative to DigitalColor Meter, you can check out [Point&Paste](https://github.com/Vaccarini-Lorenzo/Point-and-Paste). The idea is pretty simple: Just place your cursor on top of the color you want to copy and press a key of your choice to copy its hex into the clipboard.